# Obtain on screen HTML from JavaFX WebView/WebEngine

Tags: html, javafx, webview, webengine

I've been looking for a way to obtain the HTML that is currently on the screen of a JavaFX WebView/WebEngine.
I've tried:

```
(String) javaWeb.webEngine.executeScript("document.documentElement.outerHTML");
```

However, this does not give me everything I'm looking at from a Google Chrome "Inspect" viewpoint.
I have also tried:

```
try {
    URL url = new URL("https://google.com/");
    URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
    InputStream is = con.getInputStream();

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String line = null;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        html += line + "\n";
    }
}
catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.toString());
}
```

Which gives me similar results to the JavaScript execution.

Is it possible to retrieve the same data that you see from a Google Chrome "Inspect"? I just want the full raw HTML as text so I can parse through it.

Comment: use [`JSoup`](https://jsoup.org/).

Comment: @Sedrick, I am now trying JSoup, and the doc.html(); is outputting the same as the first line I tried above here.  Is there a different method I should be using?

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to see. It looks exactly like it's supposed to look when I do it.

Comment: So I can see the page code change when I change pages in the webview, however, it is missing so much data.  It's like I'm looking at 2 different pages.  I can tell it's the right page (well, it has my name in the page data I pulled, so I think it's a step in the right direction), but it doesn't have the on page text in the HTML like it does in the Chrome "inspect" context.

Comment: @Sedrick 

Java
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1dt7xH2QBfB2g6Pw9SZsR2245ZSaplPbD

Chrome
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WBScl8vGaTvRYX58ZgExPNUaGXh84hzx

Very clear difference in content...

Answer (score 0):

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://www.google.com").get();
System.out.println(document.toString());
```

> Here is the start of what I get.

```
<!doctype html>
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta content="Search the world's information, including webpages, images, videos and more. Google has many special features to help you find exactly what you're looking for." name="description">
  <meta content="noodp" name="robots">
  <meta content="/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png" itemprop="image">
  <link href="/images/branding/product/ico/googleg_lodp.ico" rel="shortcut icon">
  <meta content="origin" name="referrer">
  <title>Google</title>
  <script nonce="F54lcLMxzmjjxvSrxgcWwg==">(function(){window.google={kEI:'jKawWuCTHZKizwLD66PQDA',kEXPI:'31',authuser:0,kscs:'c9c918f0_jKawWuCTHZKizwLD66PQDA',u:'c9c918f0',kGL:'US'};google.kHL='en';})();(function(){google.lc=[];google.li=0;google.getEI=function(a){for(var b;a&&(!a.getAttribute||!(b=a.getAttribute("eid")));)a=a.parentNode;return b||google.kEI};google.getLEI=function(a){for(var b=null;a&&(!a.getAttribute||!(b=a.getAttribute("leid")));)a=a.parentNode;return b};google.https=function(){return"https:"==window.location.protocol};google.ml=function(){return null};google.wl=function(a,b){try{google.ml(Error(a),!1,b)}catch(d){}};google.time=function(){return(new Date).getTime()};google.log=function(a,b,d,c,g){if(a=google.logUrl(a,b,d,c,g)){b=new Image;var e=google.lc,f=google.li;e[f]=b;b.onerror=b.onload=b.onabort=function(){delete e[f]};google.vel&&google.vel.lu&&google.vel.lu(a);b.src=a;google.li=f+1}};google.logUrl=function(a,b,d,c,g){var e="",f=google.ls||"";d||-1!=b.search("&ei=")||(e="&ei="+google.getEI(c),-1==b.search("&lei=")&&(c=google.getLEI(c))&&(e+="&lei="+c));c="";!d&&google.cshid&&-1==b.search("&cshid=")&&(c="&cshid="+google.cshid);a=d||"/"+(g||"gen_204")+"?atyp=i&ct="+a+"&cad="+b+e+f+"&zx="+google.time()+c;/^http:/i.test(a)&&google.https()&&(google.ml(Error("a"),!1,{src:a,glmm:1}),a="");return a};}).call(this);(function(){google.y={};google.x=function(a,b){if(a)var c=a.id;else{do c=Math.random();while(google.y[c])}google.y[c]=[a,b];return!1};google.lm=[];google.plm=function(a){google.lm.push.apply(google.lm,a)};google.lq=[];google.load=function(a,b,c){google.lq.push([[a],b,c])};google.loadAll=function(a,b){google.lq.push([a,b])};}).call(this);google.f={};(function(){google.hs={h:true};})();(function(){google.c={c:{a:true,d:true,i:false,m:true,n:false}};google.sn='webhp';(function(){var e={gen204:"iml",clearcut:8};var f=function(a,b,c){a.addEventListener?a.removeEventListener(b,c,!1):a.attachEvent&&a.detachEvent("on"+b,c)},h=function(a,b,c){g.push({g:a,h:b,l:c});a.addEventListener?a.addEventListener(b,c,!1):a.attachEvent&&a.attachEvent("on"+b,c)},g=[];google.timers={};google.startTick=function(a,b){var c=b&&google.timers[b].t?google.timers[b].t.start:google.time();google.timers[a]={t:{start:c},e:{},m:{}};(c=window.performance)&&c.now&&(google.timers[a].wsrt=Math.floor(c.now()))};google.tick=function(a,b,c){google.timers[a]||google.startTick(a);c=void 0!==c?c:google.time();b instanceof Array||(b=[b]);for(var d=0;d<b.length;++d)google.timers[a].t[b[d].clearcut]={key:b[d],ts:c}};google.c.e=function(a,b,c){google.timers[a].e[b]=c};google.c.b=function(a){var b=google.timers.load.m;b[a]&&google.wl("ch_mab",{m:a});b[a]=!0};google.c.u=function(a){var b=google.timers.load.m;if(b[a]){b[a]=!1;for(a in b)if(b[a])return;google.csiReport()}else google.wl("ch_mnb",{m:a})};google.rll=function(a,b,c){var d=function(b){c(b);f(a,"load",d);f(a,"error",d)};h(a,"load",d);b&&h(a,"error",d)};google.ull=function(){for(var a;a=g.shift();)f(a.g,a.h,a.l)};google.iTick=function(a){var b=google.time();google.tick("load",e,b);a=a.id||a.src||a.name;google.timers.iml||google.startTick("iml");google.timers.iml.t[a]=b;google.c.c.a&&(google.timers.aft||google.startTick("aft"),google.timers.aft.t[a]=b)};google.afte=!0;google.aft=function(a){google.c.c.a&&google.afte&&(google.timers.aft||google.startTick("aft"),google.timers.aft.t[a.id||a.src||a.name]=google.time())};google.startTick("webaft");google.startTick("load");google.c.b("pr");google.c.b("xe");}).call(this);})();var a=window.location,b=a.href.indexOf("#");if(0<=b){var c=a.href.substring(b+1);/(^|&)q=/.test(c)&&-1==c.indexOf("#")&&a.replace("/search?"+c.replace(/(^|&)fp=[^&]*/g,"")+"&cad=h")};(function(){var k=this,l=function(){},t=Date.now||function(){return+new Date};var v={};var w=function(a,d){if(null===d)return!1;if("contains"in a&&1==d.nodeType)return a.contains(d);if("compareDocumentPosition"in a)return a==d||!!(a.compareDocumentPosition(d)&16);for(;d&&a!=d;)d=d.parentNode;return d==a};var B=function(a,d){return function(b){b||(b=window.event);return d.call(a,b)}},C=function(a){a=a.target||a.srcElement;!a.getAttribute&&a.parentNode&&(a=a.parentNode);return a},D="undefined"!=typeof navigator&&/Macintosh/.test(navigator.userAgent),E="undefined"!=typeof navigator&&!/Opera/.test(navigator.userAgent)&&/WebKit/.test(navigator.userAgent),aa={A:1,INPUT:1,TEXTAREA:1,SELECT:1,BUTTON:1},ba=function(){this._mouseEventsPrevented=!0},F={A:13,BUTTON:0,CHECKBOX:32,COMBOBOX:13,GRIDCELL:13,LINK:13,LISTBOX:13,MENU:0,MENUBAR:0,MENUITEM:0,MENUITEMCHECKBOX:0,MENUITEMRADIO:0,OPTION:0,RADIO:32,RADIOGROUP:32,RESET:0,SUBMIT:0,TAB:0,TREE:13,TREEITEM:13},G=function(a){return(a.getAttribute("type")||a.tagName).toUpperCase()in ca},H=function(a){return(a.getAttribute("type")||a.tagName).toUpperCase()in da},ca={CHECKBOX:!0,OPTION:!0,RADIO:!0},da={COLOR:!0,DATE:!0,DATETIME:!0,"DATETIME-LOCAL":!0,EMAIL:!0,MONTH:!0,NUMBER:!0,PASSWORD:!0,RANGE:!0,SEARCH:!0,TEL:!0,TEXT:!0,TEXTAREA:!0,TIME:!0,URL:!0,WEEK:!0},ea={A:!0,AREA:!0,BUTTON:!0,DIALOG:!0,IMG:!0,INPUT:!0,LINK:!0,MENU:!0,OPTGROUP:!0,OPTION:!0,PROGRESS:!0,SELECT:!0,TEXTAREA:!0};var I=function(){this.l=this.g=null},K=function(a,d){var b=J;b.g=a;b.l=d;return b};I.prototype.h=function(){var a=this.g;this.g&&this.g!=this.l?this.g=this.g.__owner||this.g.parentNode:this.g=null;return a};var L=function(){this.o=[];this.g=0;this.l=null;this.s=!1};L.prototype.h=function(){if(this.s)return J.h();if(this.g!=this.o.length){var a=this.o[this.g];this.g++;a!=this.l&&a&&a.__owner&&(this.s=!0,K(a.__owner,this.l));return a}return null};var J=new I,M=new L;var P=function(){this.B=[];this.g=[];this.h=[];this.s={};this.l=null;this.o=[];this.D=l;O(this,"_custom")},fa="undefined"!=typeof navigator&&/iPhone|iPad|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent),Q=String.prototype.trim?function(a){return a.trim()}:function(a){return a.replace(/^\s+/,"").replace(/\s+$/,"")},ha=/\s*;\s*/,la=function(a,d){return function(b){var c=d;if("_custom"==c){c=b.detail;if(!c||!c._type)return;c=c._type}if("click"==c&&(D&&b.metaKey||!D&&b.ctrlKey||2==b.which||null==b.which&&4==b.button||
"auxclick"==b.type||b.shiftKey))c="clickmod";else{var e=b.which||b.keyCode||b.key;E&&3==e&&(e=13);if(13!=e&&32!=e)e=!1;else{var f=C(b),q=(f.getAttribute("role")||f.type||f.tagName).toUpperCase(),h;(h="keydown"!=b.type)||("getAttribute"in f?(h=(f.getAttribute("role")||f.tagName).toUpperCase(),h=!H(f)&&("COMBOBOX"!=h||"INPUT"!=h)&&!f.isContentEditable):h=!1,h=!h);(h=h||b.ctrlKey||b.shiftKey||b.altKey||b.metaKey||G(f)&&32==e)||((h=f.tagName in aa)||(h=f.getAttributeNode("tabindex"),h=null!=h&&h.specified),h=!(h&&!f.disabled));h?e=!1:(f="INPUT"!=f.tagName.toUpperCase()||f.type,h=!(q in F)&&13==e,e=(0==F[q]%e||h)&&!!f)}e&&(c="clickkey")}q=b.srcElement||b.target;e=R(c,b,q,"",null);b.path?(M.o=b.path,M.g=0,M.l=this,M.s=!1,f=M):f=K(q,this);for(;h=f.h();){var m=h;var g=m;h=c;var p=g.__jsaction;if(!p){var u=null;"getAttribute"in g&&(u=g.getAttribute("jsaction"));if(u){p=v[u];if(!p){p={};for(var x=u.split(ha),y=0,ia=x?x.length:0;y<ia;y++){var r=x[y];if(r){var z=r.indexOf(":"),N=-1!=z,ja=N?Q(r.substr(0,z)):"click";r=N?Q(r.substr(z+1)):r;p[ja]=r}}v[u]=p}g.__jsaction=p}else p=ka,g.__jsaction=p}"clickkey"==h?h="click":"click"!=h||p.click||(h="clickonly");g={w:h,action:p[h]||"",event:null,C:!1};e=R(g.w,g.event||b,q,g.action||"",m,e.timeStamp);if(g.C||g.action)break}e&&"touchend"==e.eventType&&(e.event._preventMouseEvents=ba);if(g&&g.action){if(g="clickkey"==c)g=C(b),g=(g.type||g.tagName).toUpperCase(),(g=32==(b.which||b.keyCode||b.key)&&"CHECKBOX"!=g)||(g=C(b),q=(g.getAttribute("role")||g.tagName).toUpperCase(),g=g.tagName.toUpperCase()in ea&&"A"!=q&&!G(g)&&!H(g)||"BUTTON"==q);g&&(b.preventDefault?b.preventDefault():b.returnValue=!1);if("mouseenter"==c||"mouseleave"==c)if(g=b.relatedTarget,!("mouseover"==b.type&&"mouseenter"==c||"mouseout"==b.type&&"mouseleave"==c)||g&&(g===m||w(m,g)))e.action="",e.actionElement=null;else{c={};for(var n in b)"function"!==typeof b[n]&&"srcElement"!==n&&"target"!==n&&(c[n]=b[n]);c.type="mouseover"==b.type?"mouseenter":"mouseleave";c.target=c.srcElement=m;c.bubbles=!1;e.event=
c;e.targetElement=m}}else e.action="",e.actionElement=null;m=e;a.l&&(n=R(m.eventType,m.event,m.targetElement,m.action,m.actionElement,m.timeStamp),"clickonly"==n.eventType&&(n.eventType="click"),a.l(n,!0));if(m.actionElement){"A"!=m.actionElement.tagName||"click"!=m.eventType&&"clickmod"!=m.eventType||m.actionElement.hasAttribute("data-unjs")&&null==a.l||(b.preventDefault?b.preventDefault():b.returnValue=!1);if(a.l)a.l(m);else{a.D(m);if((n=k.document)&&!n.createEvent&&n.createEventObject)try{var A=
n.createEventObject(b)}catch(oa){A=b}else A=b;m.event=A;a.o.push(m)}if("touchend"==m.event.type&&m.event._mouseEventsPrevented){b=m.event;for(var pa in b);t()}}}},R=function(a,d,b,c,e,f){return{eventType:a,event:d,targetElement:b,action:c,actionElement:e,timeStamp:f||t()}},ka={},ma=function(a,d){return function(b){var c=a,e=d,f=!1;"mouseenter"==c?c="mouseover":"mouseleave"==c&&(c="mouseout");if(b.addEventListener){if("focus"==c||"blur"==c||"error"==c||"load"==c)f=!0;b.addEventListener(c,e,f)}else b.attachEvent&&
("focus"==c?c="focusin":"blur"==c&&(c="focusout"),e=B(b,e),b.attachEvent("on"+c,e));return{w:c,v:e,capture:f}}},O=function(a,d){if(!a.s.hasOwnProperty(d)){var b=la(a,d),c=ma(d,b);a.s[d]=b;a.B.push(c);for(b=0;b<a.g.length;++b){var e=a.g[b];e.h.push(c.call(null,e.g))}"click"==d&&O(a,"keydown")}};P.prototype.v=function(a){return this.s[a]};var V=function(a,d){var b=new na(d),c;a:{for(c=0;c<a.g.length;c++)if(S(a.g[c],d)){c=!0;break a}c=!1}if(c)return a.h.push(b),b;T(a,b);a.g.push(b);U(a);return b},U=function(a){for(var d=a.h.concat(a.g),b=[],c=[],e=0;e<a.g.length;++e){var f=a.g[e];W(f,d)?(b.push(f),X(f)):c.push(f)}for(e=0;e<a.h.length;++e)f=a.h[e],W(f,d)?b.push(f):(c.push(f),T(a,f));a.g=c;a.h=b},T=function(a,d){var b=d.g;fa&&(b.style.cursor="pointer");for(b=0;b<a.B.length;++b)d.h.push(a.B[b].call(null,d.g))},Y=function(a,d){a.l=d;a.o&&
(0<a.o.length&&d(a.o),a.o=null)},na=function(a){this.g=a;this.h=[]},S=function(a,d){for(var b=a.g,c=d;b!=c&&c.parentNode;)c=c.parentNode;return b==c},W=function(a,d){for(var b=0;b<d.length;++b)if(d[b].g!=a.g&&S(d[b],a.g))return!0;return!1},X=function(a){for(var d=0;d<a.h.length;++d){var b=a.g,c=a.h[d];b.removeEventListener?b.removeEventListener(c.w,c.v,c.capture):b.detachEvent&&b.detachEvent("on"+c.w,c.v)}a.h=[]};var Z=new P;V(Z,window.document.documentElement);O(Z,"click");O(Z,"focus");O(Z,"focusin");O(Z,"blur");O(Z,"focusout");O(Z,"error");O(Z,"load");O(Z,"change");O(Z,"dblclick");O(Z,"input");O(Z,"keyup");O(Z,"keydown");O(Z,"keypress");O(Z,"mousedown");O(Z,"mouseenter");O(Z,"mouseleave");O(Z,"mouseout");O(Z,"mouseover");O(Z,"mouseup");O(Z,"paste");O(Z,"touchstart");O(Z,"touchend");O(Z,"touchcancel");O(Z,"speech");(function(a){google.jsad=function(d){Y(a,d)};google.jsaac=function(d){return V(a,d)};google.jsarc=function(d){X(d);for(var b=!1,c=0;c<a.g.length;++c)if(a.g[c]===d){a.g.splice(c,1);b=!0;break}if(!b)for(c=0;c<a.h.length;++c)if(a.h[c]===d){a.h.splice(c,1);break}U(a)}})(Z);window.gws_wizbind=function(a){return{trigger:function(d){var b=a.v(d.type);b||(O(a,d.type),b=a.v(d.type));var c=d.target||d.srcElement;b&&b.call(c.ownerDocument.documentElement,d)},bind:function(d){Y(a,d)}}}(Z);}).call(this);(function(){var a=[];google.jsc={xx:a,x:function(b){a.push(b)}};}).call(this);google.arwt=function(a){a.href=document.getElementById(a.id.substring(1)).href;return!0};(function(){var f=function(){this.h="";this.o=e};f.prototype.s=!0;var g=/^(?:(?:https?|mailto|ftp):|[^:/?#]*(?:[/?#]|$))/i,e={},h=function(a){var c=new f;c.h=a;return c};h("about:blank");var k=function(a,c){if(c instanceof f)var b=c;else b=c,b instanceof f||(b=b.s?b.h:String(b),g.test(b)||(b="about:invalid#zClosurez"),b=h(b));a.href=b instanceof f&&b.constructor===f&&b.o===e?b.h:"type_error:SafeUrl"};function l(a){return a?(a=a.getAttribute("data-ved"))?"&ved="+a:"":""}function m(a){return new Promise(function(c){try{var b=new XMLHttpRequest;b.open("GET",a);b.onreadystatechange=function(){4==b.readyState&&c()};b.send()}catch(d){c()}})}function n(a){return a.getAttribute("data-cts")?"&cts="+(new Date).getTime():""};google.ausb=function(a){if(!a)return google.ml(Error("b"),!1),!0;if(a.getAttribute("data-sbv2")){var c=a.href,b=/[?&]adurl=([^&]+)/.exec(c);if(b&&/[?&]ae=1(&|$)/.test(c))try{var d={g:c+"&act=1",l:decodeURIComponent(b[1])}}catch(p){google.ml(Error("a`"+c),!1),d=null}else d=null;d&&(a.getAttribute("data-sbd")?(d=d.g+"&ri=8&shc=1&ictx=1"+n(a),navigator.sendBeacon&&navigator.sendBeacon(d,"")?k(a,a.href+"&ri=9"):k(a,a.href+"&ri=10")):(c=0,a.dataset.ampAd&&(b=a?(b=/[?&]ved=([^&]+)/.exec(a.href))?b[1]:"":"",a.dataset.ved=b,a.dataset.ampc?c=1:a.dataset.ampd&&(c=2),0!=c&&(b=d.g+"&ri=5",2==c&&(b+="&ampt=1&shc=1",d.g+="&ampt=0"),google.f.c9ZYY=m(b))),1==c?k(a,d.l):(c=d.g+"&ri=1"+n(a),navigator.sendBeacon&&navigator.sendBeacon(c,"")?k(a,d.l):k(a,a.href+"&ri=2"))))}else d="",a.getAttribute("data-arwt")?a.id&&(d=l(document.getElementById(a.id.substring(1)))):d=l(a),c=a.getAttribute("data-sbt"),b=a.getAttribute("data-sbf"),c&&b&&navigator.sendBeacon&&navigator.sendBeacon(c+d+"&bt=1","")?a.href=b:a.href+=
"&bt=2";return!0};}).call(this);</script>
  <style>[dir='ltr'],[dir='rtl']{unicode-bidi:-webkit-isolate;unicode-bidi:isolate}bdo[dir='ltr'],bdo[dir='rtl']{unicode-bidi:bidi-override;unicode-bidi:-webkit-isolate-override;unicode-bidi:isolate-override}#logo{display:block;overflow:hidden;position:relative}#logo img{border:0;}#logo span{background:url(/images/nav_logo242.png) no-repeat;cursor:pointer;overflow:hidden}#logocont{z-index:1;padding-left:13px;padding-right:10px;padding-top:7px}#logocont.ddl{padding-top:3px}.big #logocont{padding-left:13px;padding-right:12px}.sbibod{background-color:#fff;height:44px;vertical-align:top;border-radius:2px;box-shadow:0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.16),0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.08);transition:box-shadow 200ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1);}.lst{border:0;margin-top:6px;margin-bottom:0}.lst:focus{outline:none}.gsfi,.lst{font:16px arial,sans-serif;line-height:34px;height:34px !important;}.lst-c{overflow:hidden}#gs_st0{line-height:44px;padding:0 8px;margin-top:-1px;position:static}.srp #gs_st0{padding:0 2px 0 8px}.gsfs{font:16px arial,sans-serif}.lsb{background:transparent;border:0;font-size:0;height:30px;outline:0;text-align:left;width:100%}.sbico{display:inline-block;height:24px;width:24px;cursor:pointer;vertical-align:middle;color:#4285f4}.sbico-c{background:transparent;border:0;float:right;height:44px;line-height:44px;margin-top:-1px;outline:0;padding-right:16px;position:relative;top:-1px}.hp .sbico-c{display:none}#sblsbb{text-align:center;border-bottom-left-radius:0;border-top-left-radius:0;height:44px;margin:0;padding:0;}#sbds{border:0;margin-left:0}.hp .nojsb,.srp .jsb{display:none}.kpbb,.kprb,.kpgb,.kpgrb{border-radius:2px;border-radius:2px;color:#fff}.kpbb:hover,.kprb:hover,.kpgb:hover,.kpgrb:hover{box-shadow:0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);box-shadow:0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);color:#fff}.kpbb:active,.kprb:active,.kpgb:active,.kpgrb:active{box-shadow:inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);box-shadow:inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3)}.kpbb{background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(#4d90fe),to(#4787ed));background-color:#4d90fe;background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#4d90fe,#4787ed);background-image:linear-gradient(top,#4d90fe,#4787ed);border:1px solid #3079ed}.kpbb:hover{background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(#4d90fe),to(#357ae8));background-color:#357ae8;background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#4d90fe,#357ae8);background-image:linear-gradient(top,#4d90fe,#357ae8);border:1px solid #2f5bb7}a.kpbb:link,a.kpbb:visited{color:#fff}.kprb{background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(#dd4b39),to(#d14836));background-color:#dd4b39;background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#dd4b39,#d14836);background-image:linear-gradient(top,#dd4b39,#d14836);border:1px solid #dd4b39}.kprb:hover{background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(#dd4b39),to(#c53727));background-color:#c53727;background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#dd4b39,#c53727);background-image:linear-gradient(top,#dd4b39,#c53727);border:1px solid #b0281a;border-bottom-color:#af301f}.kprb:active{background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(#dd4b39),to(#b0281a));background-color:#b0281a;background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#dd4b39,#b0281a);background-image:linear-gradient(top,#dd4b39,#b0281a)}.kpgb{background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(#3d9400),to(#398a00));background-color:#3d9400;background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#3d9400,#398a00);background-image:linear-gradient(top,#3d9400,#398a00);border:1px solid #29691d}.kpgb:hover{background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(#3d9400),to(#368200));background-color:#368200;background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#3d9400,#368200);background-image:linear-gradient(top,#3d9400,#368200);border:1px solid #2d6200}.kpgrb{background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(#f5f5f5),to(#f1f1f1));background-color:#f5f5f5;background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#f5f5f5,#f1f1f1);background-image:linear-gradient(top,#f5f5f5,#f1f1f1);border:1px solid #dcdcdc;color:#555}.kpgrb:hover{background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(#f8f8f8),to(#f1f1f1));background-color:#f8f8f8;background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#f8f8f8,#f1f1f1);background-image:linear-gradient(top,#f8f8f8,#f1f1f1);border:1px solid #dcdcdc;color:#333}a.kpgrb:link,a.kpgrb:visited{color:#555}#sfopt{display:inline-block;float:right;line-height:normal}.lsd{font-size:11px;position:absolute;top:3px;left:16px}.sbsb_g{margin:3px 0 4px}.jhp input[type="submit"],.sbdd_a input,.gbqfba{background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(#f5f5f5),to(#f1f1f1));background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#f5f5f5,#f1f1f1);-webkit-border-radius:2px;-webkit-user-select:none;background-color:#f2f2f2;border:1px solid #f2f2f2;border-radius:2px;color:#757575;cursor:default;font-family:arial,sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;margin:11px 4px;min-width:54px;padding:0 16px;text-align:center}.gbqfba.gbqfba-hvr{font-size:13px}.jhp input[type="submit"],.gbqfba{height:36px;line-height:27px}.sbdd_a input{height:100%}.jhp input[type="submit"]:hover,.sbdd_a input:hover,.gbqfba:hover{background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(#f8f8f8),to(#f1f1f1));background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#f8f8f8,#f1f1f1);-webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);background-color:#f8f8f8;background-image:linear-gradient(top,#f8f8f8,#f1f1f1);background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top,#f8f8f8,#f1f1f1);border:1px solid #c6c6c6;box-shadow:0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);color:#222}.jhp input[type="submit"]:focus,.sbdd_a input:focus{border:1px solid #4d90fe;outline:none}.sbdd_a input{margin:6px;}span.lsbb,.lsb input{-webkit-transition:all 0.18s}@media only screen and (max-height:650px){span.lsbb{height:17px}}.tsf{background:none}.tsf-p{position:relative;}.logocont{left:0;position:absolute;}.sfibbbc{padding-bottom:2px;padding-top:3px;margin-top:-3px;width:632px}.sbtc{position:relative}.sbibtd{line-height:0;overflow:visible;white-space:nowrap}.sbibps{padding:0 9px 0 16px;width:466px;}.big .sbibps{width:550px}.sfopt{height:28px;position:relative}#sform{height:65px}.hp .sfsbc{display:none}#searchform{width:100%}.hp #searchform{position:absolute;top:311px}.srp #searchform{position:absolute;top:20px}#sfdiv{max-width:484px}.hp .big #sfdiv{max-width:584px;margin:-1px 0px 1px}.srp #sfdiv{max-width:none;overflow:hidden}.srp #tsf{position:relative;}.hp .tsf-p{padding-top:8px}.sfsbc{display:inline-block;float:right;margin-right:1px;vertical-align:top;width:42px;margin-right:0}.sfbg{background:#fafafa;height:69px;left:0;position:absolute;width:100%}.sfbgg{background-color:#fafafa;height:65px}#pocs{background:#fff1a8;color:#000;font-size:10pt;margin:0;padding:5px 7px}#pocs.sft{background:transparent;color:#777}#pocs a{color:#11c}#pocs.sft a{color:#36c}#pocs>div{margin:0;padding:0}#cnt{padding-top:20px;}#subform_ctrl{min-height:0px}@-webkit-keyframes gb__a{0%{opacity:0}50%{opacity:1}}@keyframes gb__a{0%{opacity:0}50%{opacity:1}}.gb_bb{display:none!important}.gb_cb{visibility:hidden}.gb_da .gb_b{background-position:-132px -38px;opacity:.55}.gb_ea .gb_da .gb_b{background-position:-132px -38px}.gb_X .gb_da .gb_b{background-position:-463px -35px;opacity:1}.gb_fa.gb_ga{min-height:196px;overflow-y:auto;width:320px}.gb_ha{-webkit-transition:height .2s ease-in-out;transition:height .2s ease-in-out}.gb_ia{background:#fff;margin:0;min-height:100px;padding:28px;padding-right:27px;text-align:left;white-space:normal;width:265px}.gb_ja{background:#f5f5f5;cursor:pointer;height:40px;overflow:hidden}.gb_ka{position:relative}.gb_ja{display:block;line-height:40px;text-align:center;width:320px}.gb_ka{display:block;line-height:40px;text-align:center}.gb_ka.gb_la{line-height:0}.gb_ja,.gb_ja:visited,.gb_ja:active,.gb_ka,.gb_ka:visited{color:rgba(0,0,0,0.87);text-decoration:none}.gb_ka:active{color:rgba(0,0,0,0.87)}#gb a.gb_ja,#gb a.gb_ja:visited,#gb a.gb_ja:active,#gb a.gb_ka,#gb a.gb_ka:visited{color:rgba(0,0,0,0.87);text-decoration:none}#gb a.gb_ka:active{color:rgba(0,0,0,0.87)}.gb_ka,.gb_ia{display:none}.gb_ba,.gb_ba+.gb_ka,.gb_ma .gb_ka,.gb_ma .gb_ia{display:block}.gb_ka:hover,.gb_ka:active,#gb a.gb_ka:hover,#gb a.gb_ka:active{text-decoration:underline}.gb_ka{border-bottom:1px solid #ebebeb;left:28px;width:264px}.gb_ma .gb_ja{display:none}.gb_ka:last-child{border-bottom-width:0}.gb_na .gb_O{display:initial}.gb_na.gb_oa{height:100px;text-align:center}.gb_na.gb_oa img{padding:34px 0;height:32px;width:32px}.gb_na .gb_2{background-image:url('//ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/p1_c82e4f78.png');-webkit-background-size:64px 2341px;background-size:64px 2341px;background-position:0 -828px}.gb_na .gb_2+img{border:0;margin:8px;height:48px;width:48px}.gb_na div.gb_pa{background:#ffa;-webkit-border-radius:5px;border-radius:5px;padding:5px;text-align:center}.gb_na.gb_qa,.gb_na.gb_ra{padding-bottom:0}.gb_na.gb_sa,.gb_na.gb_ra{padding-top:0}.gb_na.gb_ra a,.gb_na.gb_sa a{top:0}.gb_ta .gb_ja{margin-top:0;position:static}.gb_ua{display:inline-block}.gb_va{margin:-12px 28px 28px;position:relative;width:264px;-webkit-border-radius:2px;border-radius:2px;-webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1),0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);box-shadow:0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1),0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1)}.gb_4{background-image:url('//ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/p1_c82e4f78.png');-webkit-background-size:64px 2341px;background-size:64px 2341px;display:inline-block;margin:8px;vertical-align:middle;height:64px;width:64px}.gb_wa{color:#262626;display:inline-block;font:13px/18px Arial,sans-serif;margin-right:80px;padding:10px 10px 10px 0;vertical-align:middle;white-space:normal}.gb_xa{font:16px/24px Arial,sans-serif}.gb_ya,#gb#gb .gb_ya{color:#427fed;text-decoration:none}.gb_ya:hover,#gb#gb .gb_ya:hover{text-decoration:underline}.gb_za .gb_ia{position:relative}.gb_za .gb_O{position:absolute;top:28px;left:28px}.gb_ja.gb_Aa{display:none;height:0}.gb_db{-webkit-background-size:32px 32px;background-size:32px 32px;-webkit-border-radius:50%;border-radius:50%;display:block;margin:-1px;overflow:hidden;position:relative;height:32px;width:32px;z-index:0}@media (min-resolution:1.25dppx),(-o-min-device-pixel-ratio:5/4),(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:1.25),(min-device-pixel-ratio:1.25){.gb_db::before{display:inline-block;-webkit-transform:scale(.5);transform:scale(.5);-webkit-transform-origin:left 0;transform-origin:left 0}.gb_Eb::before{display:inline-block;-webkit-transform:scale(.5);transform:scale(.5);-webkit-transform-origin:left 0;transform-origin:left 0}}.gb_db:hover,.gb_db:focus{-webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);box-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15)}.gb_db:active{-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);box-shadow:inset 0 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15)}.gb_db:active::after{background:rgba(0,0,0,.1);-webkit-border-radius:50%;border-radius:50%;content:'';display:block;height:100%}.gb_eb{cursor:pointer;line-height:30px;min-width:30px;opacity:.75;overflow:hidden;vertical-align:middle;text-overflow:ellipsis}.gb_b.gb_eb{width:auto}.gb_eb:hover,.gb_eb:focus{opacity:.85}.gb_fb .gb_eb,.gb_fb .gb_gb{line-height:26px}#gb#gb.gb_fb a.gb_eb,.gb_fb .gb_gb{font-size:11px;height:auto}.gb_hb{border-top:4px solid #000;border-left:4px dashed transparent;border-right:4px dashed transparent;display:inline-block;margin-left:6px;opacity:.75;vertical-align:middle}.gb_ib:hover .gb_hb{opacity:.85}.gb_X .gb_eb,.gb_X .gb_hb{opacity:1}#gb#gb.gb_X.gb_X a.gb_eb,#gb#gb .gb_X.gb_X a.gb_eb{color:#fff}.gb_X.gb_X .gb_hb{border-top-color:#fff;opacity:1}.gb_ea .gb_db:hover,.gb_X .gb_db:hover,.gb_ea .gb_db:focus,.gb_X .gb_db:focus{-webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);box-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2)}.gb_jb .gb_kb,.gb_lb
```

Comment: Yup, did exactly that.  Please see my above comment with image/text document with the varying outputs.

Comment: This is the exact thing I see when I inspect

Comment: You're right.  On Google.com it does have everything.  I'm at a loss for why it isn't showing me everything on this other page.  If I provide it to you, do you think you could take a look?